# Enable both GET & POST call on an operation contract

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config

Can I make an operation contract accessible on both GET & POST method?
Do we have any attribute or property for it?
I am able to call it on either POST with following attribute

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

or on GET with following attribute

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

or

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

but I want to call the operation contract on both requests. Any suggestion on how to achieve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you required such condition?

Comment: Why don't you create two operation contract(GET, POST) having same signature and call same method internally from both the operation contract.

Comment: I don't know whether my client will call my service on ajax or from codebehind. So I want to make my service callable from both ajax & codebehind.

Currently I am doing the same, I have two methods with same functionality one is get enabled & the other is post enabled. But, I don't find this efficient. So, I was thinking of something with which I can my service accessible over both get & post

Comment: A service can be called from either Ajax or code behind but you have to define your service type (GET, POST, PUT etc), you can't simply allow client to call as they want, make your service POST or GET and ask client to do a GET or POST request , doesn't matter either from Ajax or code behind, but they have to do the same request what you defined for service.